# Migrate existing ROR app to GAE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, activerecord, jruby, datamapper

I have managed to run a basic rails app1 on App Engine using:
http://gist.github.com/268192

So, on my basic app2, I install CE, which works fine on local machine.
(communityengine.org)

But, when I follow the same steps on my actual app2, where
community_engine plugin is installed and all the gems are frozen, the
app engine installer script asks for to over write various files like
boot.rb, routes.rb, which I don't allow.

So, as expected, when I publish the rails + ce app to GAE, it's not
published and it also screws the local installation of CE on app2.

So, the problem is obvious, CE uses ActiveRecord, and GAE uses
DataMapper.

So, my question can also be rephrased as: **Can we migrate an existing
ROR App using Active Record to GAE which uses DataMapper?**

PS: This is my first project on ROR and GAE.

Comment: No one has tried this before?

Comment: If you want your rails app in the cloud, why don't you give [heroku](http://heroku.com/) a try? It's free for starters, and you can buy more power if you need to. I can't help you with you GAE problem, because I never tried it.

Comment: Yea, I have just started with heroku, it sounds promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly port CE to use DataMapper, but it being a Rails Engine it would probably be more fitting to keep it as an ActiveRecord-based project. The comment about Heroku is sound. You'll find much better support, and most of the time, things Just Work(tm). Give Heroku a try.